# Does not name a type error when using makeTime

Tags: arduino-uno, time

I am getting a "does not name a type" error when trying to use `makeTime()` from the Time.h library, code snippet as follows:

```
#include<Time.h>

tmElements_t tmet;
tmet.Year = 2013-1970;
tmet.Month = 8;
tmet.Day = 28;
tmet.Hour = 18;
tmet.Minute = 30;
tmet.Second = 0;

time_t dateMet = makeTime(tmet);
```

Alternatively I've also tried `time_t dateMet = maketime(&tmet);` with the same result. I am no expert so go easy on me but am I missing something small here?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to access the '*properties*' (i.e. the *members*) of the `tmet` variable in a scope where they aren't accessible (outside of a code block). In this global scope of the program the compiler expects a type name on the left side of a statement (i.e. a variable or type declaration), but `tmet`'s members like `tmet.Year` aren't types in and of themselves.

There are two solutions. You can move the access to the members of `tmet` into a code block like the `setup` function:

```
#include <Time.h>

tmElements_t tmet;
time_t dateMet;

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
    tmet.Year = 2013-1970;
    tmet.Month = 8;
    tmet.Day = 28;
    tmet.Hour = 18;
    tmet.Minute = 30;
    tmet.Second = 0;

    dateMet = makeTime(tmet);
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:

}
```

Or you could declare and define `tmet` in one statement, which has a different syntax (since you have to provide the content of a `tmElements_t` in a single line:

```
#include <Time.h>

tmElements_t tmet2 = { 2013-1970, 8, 28, 18, 30, 0 };

time_t dateMet2 = makeTime(tmet2);

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:

}
```

Both versions work right away from within the Arduino IDE (i.e. I tested them).